# Enable Http Compression in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, compression, iis-7.5

I'm trying to enable HTTP compression to my web site, my server is running Windows 2008R2 and IIS 7.5.

I followed these steps:

1. installed static and dynamic compression through the Serve manager.
2. Enable both static and dynamic option under my web site (mySite-Compression).

In my `web.config` file I have included:

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true"  doStaticCompression="true"/>
```

When I checked my page headers the page's are not compressed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've completed the correct steps.  It may be the test that is giving a false positive. If your test software doesn't accept compression then the web server won't offer compression.

A good web test can be found on the homepage of: http://www.port80software.com/.  Use that to confirm for sure that it's not compressing.